# What does include_plotlyjs="cdn" in plotly python do to the generated HTML?

Tags: python, cdn, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

My goal is to generate an interactive html file from plotly fig and embed this html in my website. I was previously using `fig.write_html('name.html')`, but in the generated HTML, there are some unwanted symbols like ampersands `&&`.
Now, I tried adding cdn like `fig.write_html('name.html', include_plotlyjs="cdn")`, which solves the `&&` problem but I have some questions about this:

1. On using cdn, is my data still secured/private, and can there be some possible complications on embedding this html to my website?
2. Is there any better/alternate way of removing the `&&` symbols/cleaning the initial html file generated by plotly?

TIA

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Show examples of the code and the emitted HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The `include_plotlyjs="cdn"` parameter causes a script tag to be included in the HTML output that references the Plotly CDN ("content delivery network"). This offloads the work of providing the necessary javascript from your server to a more scalable one. A browser will typically cache this making subsequent page loads faster.

Your data security/privacy is not affected by this option.

If the unwanted text you refer to is part of the Plotly JavaScript, it must be loaded however this solution will keep it from appearing in your HTML.

See the documentation for [`to_html`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html#plotly.graph_objects.Figure.to_html) for more information.